# Chrome Autocomplete only fills first 3 numbers of a phone number

Tags: html, google-chrome, autocomplete

I have a field defined as follows:

```
<input name="home_phone1" placeholder="Phone Number" type="tel" id="home_phone1" maxlength="30" value="">
```

Each time I pick an item from my autocomplete list (from Chrome, no extra library or plugin), it fills all fields ok but the phone number. It only add 1 number of it (if first 2 digits are country identifier) or 3 first numbers (if no country identifier)

am I missing an attribute on the field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I add an attribute:

```
autocomplete="tel"
```

It works as expected.